# How to normalize an array of frequencies

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, normalization

I have two audio files originated from one file that i divided into a "signal" file and a "noise" file- the background.I need to know the dominant frequencies, Distributions pattern or the Frequencies of that recording in order to be able to compare different sounds emitted from different animals.

I have performed a fft on each file, and then deducted the background noises from the signal.

I don't care what happens bellow 20kHz  and above 100 kHz to me they are noise to be discarded.

Amplitude is something that i can not control, so each recording must be normalized.

what is the best way to normalize this data and make the comparisons between different recordings statistically viable ?

```
function bindel=binset(raw_data_val,signal,noise)

    %in case all the recording is only noise
    if isempty(signal)
        bindel=nan;
        return
    end

    %frequancy of sampling
    %Fs= 250000;

    %extract the signal parts and noise parts
    %"signal" is an index array of all the elemnts of the 
    %"raw data" array that contain a signal
    signal_data=raw_data_val(signal);
    noise_data=raw_data_val(noise);

    %determine the size of the signal array
    L= size(signal_data,1);

    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L(1,1));


    Y1 = fft(signal_data,NFFT)/L(1,1);

    del1=smooth(2*abs(Y1(1:NFFT/2+1)));

    Y2 = fft(noise_data,NFFT)/L(1,1);

    del2=smooth(2*abs(Y2(1:NFFT/2+1)));

    del=del1-del2;

    %combine the data into 125 bindels
    binsum=size(del)/125;
    bindel=zeros(1,125);
    for j=1:125,
        bindel(j)= sum(del((j-1)*floor(binsum(1,1))+1:j*floor(binsum(1,1))));
    end

    %%%deleting low freuqencies- testing filter set to change
    %%%everything bellow 20 khz to zero
    %%%normalizing between 1 to 0
    bindel(1:20)=0;
    bindel(100:end)=0;
    norm_bin=(bindel - min(bindel)) / ( max(bindel) - min(bindel) );


    bindel=norm_bin;

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a best way to normalize spectral data (depends the question you are trying to answer), but given that you don't care for absolute amplitude but rather the distribution of dominant frequencies I would rely on density and normalize by the sum of your spectrum:

```
norm_bin = bindel / sum(bindel)
```

I am assuming that your NFFT is the same for all recordings you compare, if this is not the case normalize taking NFFT into account:

```
norm_bin = bindel / mean(bindel)
```

Comment: is the NFFT  spouse to be the same in all the recordings? they are not.
each audio clip is a different length.
That part i didn't completely understood, i got this script half baked and continued working on it.
I'll try what you suggested, and if no one else can add to it, I'll close the thread.
thank you

Comment: If you used Welch FFT, for example you could have all spectra with the same resolution even if the recordings were of different length. You would just need to set the welch window such that it fits at least once in any of your recordings.